# Update of Android Studio to version 3.4.2

Tags: android-studio

after downloading update, java environment show errors about some conflicts " Some of the conflicts below do not have a solution, so the patch cannot be applied " And there is the list error

> contents/lib/pty4j-native/macosx/x86/libpty.dylib validate modified
>   none contents/lib/pty4j-native/macosx/x86_64/libpty.dylib validate
>   modified none contents/plugins/android/lib/libwebp_jni64.dylib
>   validate modified none
>   contents/plugins/android/resources/simpleperf/darwin-x86_64/simpleperf
>   validate modified none
>   contents/plugins/android/resources/simpleperf/darwin-x86_64/libsimpleperf_report.dylib
>   validate modified none
>   contents/plugins/android/resources/simpleperf/darwin-x86/simpleperf
>   validate modified none
>   contents/plugins/android/resources/simpleperf/darwin-x86/libsimpleperf_report.dylib
>   validate modified none contents/bin/restarter validate modified none
>   contents/bin/fsnotifier validate modified none
>   contents/bin/lldb/lib/libc++.dylib validate modified none
>   contents/bin/lldb/lib/liblldb.7.0.0.dylib validate modified none
>   contents/bin/lldb/breakpad.framework/resources/breakpadutilities.dylib
>   validate modified none contents/bin/libnst64.dylib validate modified
>   none contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/java validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/serialver validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/tnameserv validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/policytool validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/keytool validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/jdeps validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/javac validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/rmiregistry validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/jdb validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/javah validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/servertool validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/orbd validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/appletviewer validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/javap validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/javadoc validate modified none
>   contents/jre/jdk/contents/home/bin/jinfo validate modified none
>   contents/

Comment: Please avoid posting external links and try to explain your question in more detail way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually occurs when Android Studio cannot access some files.
It may be due to several reasons. Make sure the installation path is accessable and is not hidden, or system Folder.

For Best Practice you should export android studio settings from your older version, then uninstall it and reinstall the new version.
On installation it would ask you to import the previous settings. Hit Ok and you are get to go.